# Weird getExtras() being null

Tags: android

So i have a util class and in that class I start an activity like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, FacebookDialogActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("test","test");
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```

To read extras in the activity i have

```
Bundle bundle=  this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

but bundle is empty. I also checked in debug mode and they bundle is empty on the intent object. In android studio if i do evaluate  this.getIntent() it shows

```
Intent{ MyActivityName (has extras)}
```

can I not pass extras by using activity.startActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the class instead?

Like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, FacebookDialogActivity.class);
```

Also, where is this bundle coming from?

```
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

You should be able to retrieve by doing something like this:

```
String test = getIntent().getExtras().getString("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, FacebookDialogActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("test","test");
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```